# Java - Multiple visitor patterns for the same class structure

Tags: java, design-patterns, visitor-pattern, dynamic-binding

So I have a class structure of expressions, composed by, Binary Expressions, Unary Expressions, all abstract, these expanding into their specific concrete classes of operations such as Add, Sub, Mul, Not, etc...  Like such.

[image: Class Structure]

I want to create 2 visitors for each of these classes. One for toString and one to evaluate the expression (calculate the value).

The problem is, my toStringVisitor should always return a String, but the evaluateVisitor will return variable types depending on the operation (ie: Add will return an int, Lower than or Not will return a boolean, some others will return other types as well)

Can I avoid creating 2 visitor interfaces for these 2 visitors?

For example what I have right now

```
public interface Visitor {

Public int visit(Neg c);
Public int visit(Add c);
Public int visit(Sub c);
Public int visit(Mul c);
Public boolean visit(Lowerthan c);
Public boolean visit(Greaterthan c);
Public boolean visit(Equal c);
Public boolean visit(Not c);
Public boolean visit(And c);
Public boolean visit(Or c);

}
```

Will only work for the evaluateVisitor and not for the toString visitor.

Also, what is the difference between using for example:

```
Public int visit(Neg c);
Public int visit(Add c);
Public int visit(Sub c);
Public int visit(Mul c);
```

and

```
Public int visitNeg(Neg c);
Public int visitAdd(Add c);
Public int visitSub(Sub c);
Public int visitMul(Mul c);
```

I was told I should differentiate the visit methods to avoid dynamic binding issues but I can't really figure out why that would be the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make the visitor generic:

```
interface Visitor<R> {
    R visit(Neg c);
    ...
}
```

So your ToStringVisitor will implement `Visitor<String>`, and the other two will implement `Visitor<Integer>` and `Visitor<Boolean>`.

Regarding using visit() vs. visitNeg(), it's a matter of choice. Some feel that using distinct names clutters the API. Some feel using overloading make things more complex to understand, and bug-prone. I'm personally not a big fan of overloading.

Comment: I'm having trouble implementing this. For example I have a class that requires variable return types.  And Im trying to implement in the respective Evaluate visitor something like `public <T> visit(Sequence c)`, but Im having a compiler error such as `Evaluator.java:147: error: invalid method declaration; return type required
  public <T> visitSequence(Sequence c)`

Comment: Ok I wasn't getting the proper syntax down. I now realized I have to define the generic name in the class and in the method I dont use the brackets again