# Visitor design pattern: can my visitor returns a Promise or should I create a new interface

Tags: typescript, design-patterns, visitor-pattern

I am now using a Visitor pattern where I have 2 visitors using the same interface returning T. It basically looks like the schema below, but my visitor returns something.

I would like to  change the return type of one of my visitor to return a Promise.

Should I create a new interface for this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make use of `async/await`, I think it makes sense to create a new interface called `AsyncVisitor`. Every visitor you implement should, in a sense, be thought of as its own "virtual" function on an enumeration of types. However, in JavaScript, `Function` and `AsyncFunction` are two inherently different types of functions, where the latter may suspend execution and must always return a `Promise`. Therefore, it doesn't make sense to have one visitor interface to represent both regular and async functions.

While you could hypothetically implement your promise-based Visitor as just `Visitor<Promise<T>>` and `async/await` will still work, your interface would then mix and treat `Function` and `AsyncFunction` as interchangeable types, which can be unexpected if you're doing some kind of metaprogramming.

In other words, I think your interfaces should look something like this:

```
interface Visitor<T> {
  visitElementA(e: ElementA): T;
  visitElementB(e: ElementB): T;
}

interface AsyncVisitor<T> {
  visitElementAAsync(e: ElementA): Promise<T>;
  visitElementBAsync(e: ElementB): Promise<T>;
}

interface Element {
  accept<T>(v: Visitor<T>): T;
  acceptAsync<T>(v: AsyncVisitor<T>): Promise<T>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I just found this post: [Java - Multiple visitor patterns for the same class structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41027586/java-multiple-visitor-patterns-for-the-same-class-structure)

I needed to change my visitor return type:

```
Visitor1<Type1>
```

and

```
Visitor2<Promise<Type2>>
```